# Longitudinal Issues with NetCDF data

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, tools, latitude-longitude, netcdf

I am seeking advice on working with world data sets where the GCS has a positive range (0 degrees to 360 degrees). The data I am working with are [NetCDF](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/) oceanographic data and have positive coordinate values as mentioned. When displayed in a normal GCS WGS84 in ESRI's ArcGIS 10, it is offset from other data that exist in the range of -180 to 180. If I reproject it, gaps occur around the prime meridian (mostly due to its origins, sometimes as far off as 25 degrees W). My thought is to create a custom projection/coordinate system that has the positive values and hope that other world data sets reproject on the fly just fine.

Does anyone see any issues with this or have other solutions?

---

This is a screenshot of a countries data set with graticule on top to show the normal CRS of GCS. Just importing the NetCDF data as-is brings it in but the values don't start until 20.5 degrees east of the Prime Meridian.

[Normal GCS http://grafa.co/rnd/img/GCS_Normal.png](http://grafa.co/rnd/img/GCS_Normal.png)

If I choose to use the NetCDF's CRS (which is actually the same) it will reproject the world data on the fly if it is defined. Note the graticule is undefined so it does not reproject.

[Sort of reprojected GCS http://grafa.co/rnd/img/GCS_Other.png](http://grafa.co/rnd/img/GCS_Other.png)

But then if I try to reproject everything to a normal GCS with negative values, it's like wrapping a flat map of the data around the world and then it disappears when it hits the Prime Meridian.

[Sort of reprojected GCS http://grafa.co/rnd/img/reprojected.png](http://grafa.co/rnd/img/reprojected.png)

Now, I know there are no values from 0-20.5 as is stated in the metadata.

Why can't the values from rest of the data display in the gap?

I even tried a Shift in the Raster Tools to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue here is that ESRI use the centre of the grid to calculate the position, and when I have written the data, I am using the bottom left value of the cell to calculate the data.  How I resolved this, was by creating my netCDF file with an X grid origin of the centre of the first cell, then calculating each cell using that as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug now, as we have experienced the same issue.  With a bit of tooing and fromming, which ended up with me sending them details of panopoly, to view the netCDF data without the missing line.

Interestingly, this isn't solely limited to the netCDF.  If you create points, using the grids inside the netCDF, and then aggregate the points to build polygons, it will not build a polygon over the prime meridian too, it will be separate ones.

The bug is NIM070286: NetCDF Raster Layer does not display data located along prime meridian

I have requested a hot fix from ESRI Inc.

Answer (score 0):

If needed, you can easily convert your rasters to -180 180 with GDAL

http://eloiribeiro.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/coverter-imagens-0%c2%ba-360%c2%ba-a-180-180%c2%ba-com-gdal/

(in Portuguese, you will need to use Google Translate)

Comment: The link has changed to http://eloiribeiro.eu/blog/coverter-imagens-0%C2%BA-360%C2%BA-a-180-180%C2%BA-com-gdal/. Perhaps you could just add the relevant commands to the answer.