# Projection mismatch when plotting precipitation with ggplot

Tags: raster, gdal, coordinate-system, r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot accumulated precipitation in Brazil for a given period, see code below:

**Load packages**

```
library(raincpc)
library(SDMTools)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(mapproj)
```

**Use *cpcrain package* to obtain data**

```
cpc_get_rawdata(2014, 1, 01, 2014, 1, 08)

rain1 <- cpc_read_rawdata(2014, 1, 01)
rain2 <- cpc_read_rawdata(2014, 1, 02)
rain3 <- cpc_read_rawdata(2014, 1, 03)
rain4 <- cpc_read_rawdata(2014, 1, 04)
rain5 <- cpc_read_rawdata(2014, 1, 05)

rain_tot <- rain1 + rain2 + rain3 + rain4 + rain5
```

**Zoom in Brazil**

```
lon_vals <- seq(275, 330     , 0.5)
lat_vals <- seq(-60, 20      , 0.5)
reg_box <- expand.grid(lon = lon_vals, lat = lat_vals,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE)
reg_box$rain <- extract.data(reg_box, rain_tot)
reg_box$rain_chunks <- cut(reg_box$rain, breaks = c(0, 80, 160, 240, 320), include.lowest = TRUE)
```

**Use ggplot for visualization**

```
gfx_gg <- 
  ggplot(data = reg_box) +
              geom_raster(aes(lon, lat, fill = rain_chunks)) +
              scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightgrey", "red", "green", "blue")) +
              theme(axis.text = element_blank()) + # , axis.ticks = element_blank() 
              labs( x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = " Precipitation (mm)") +
              ggtitle("Rainfall over South America for selected period")
```

which, as expected, yields:

[image]

**Add state boundaries**

```
brazil1 <- getData("GADM", country = "BRA", level = 1)

gfx_gg +
  geom_polygon(data = brazil1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               color = "black", show_guide = FALSE, fill=NA) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y") +
  theme_bw()
```

But I'm getting an unexpected error:

[image]

How can I fix this (projection?) error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are experiencing is more or less a copy of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10238/longitudinal-issues-with-netcdf-data) question.

The coordinates in the rainfall data are in longitude/latitude, but with values ranging from 0 to 360, instead of -180 to 180 (as your political boundaries are).  See the GPCC spatial note here (emphasis mine):

> Spatial Coverage:
>
> - 0.5 degree latitude x 0.5 degree longitude global grid (720x180)
> - 1.0 degree latitude x 1.0 degree longitude global grid (360x180)
> - 2.5 degree latitude x 2.5 degree longitude global grid (144x72)
> - 90.0N - 90.0S, **0.0E - 360.0E**

[This](http://eloiribeiro.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/coverter-imagens-0%C2%BA-360%C2%BA-a-180-180%C2%BA-com-gdal/) blog from the above referenced answer explains how to use gdalwarp to convert the data to the standard -180, 180 coordinates.