# Tilemill and GeoTiff not working together

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, tilemill, gdalwarp

Loading in a geotiff with projection of EPSG:4326 isn't fully rendering:

The original:
[image: original geotiff]

The original in Tilemill:

[image: original]

When using gdalwarp to change the projection from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857, tilemill will 
then load the full geotiff, but the geotiff has a black strip down the center. 
[image: warped]

The warped in Tilemill:
[image: warped in Tilemill]

The command used for gdalwarp is:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -r lanczos -srcnodata 0 -dstnodata 0 -of GTiff original.tif warped.tif
```

**The question is, either how do we get gdalwarp to work correctly, without the black strip, or how do we get the original to show up correctly in Tilemill.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues with gdalwarp producing black strips around image edges.  Usually these happen around the international dateline, but your edges appear to be around the central meridian instead so it's no wonder you wind up with an empty strip in the middle of the output GeoTIFF.

Try playing around with the `-wo SOURCE_EXTRA=XXX` argument. Depending on your image resolution, you might try values anywhere between 100 - 1000 and see where the sweet spot is.

This option specifies a number of extra pixels to use during reprojection that should help minimize the effect.  You may still wind up with a small black strip, but it shouldn't be as noticeable.

More information [here](http://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html#a0ed77f9917bb96c7a9aabd73d4d06e08).

If that doesn't work, you might also try increasing work/cache memory using `-wm XXX` and `--config GDAL_CACHEMAX XXX`, where `XXX` is an integer representing megabytes.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. For the curious, here is what causes it: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10238/longitudinal-issues-with-netcdf-data

Comment: Do you know if this is cause by the original data, or just a gdalwarp problem?

Comment: I believe it's just the nature of how GDAL performs reprojection.  See this response from Frank Warmerdam to my question on the gdal-dev mailing list:  http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-March/035676.html