# TileMill Issue with Null values

Tags: tilemill, cartocss, tilestache

I have this original image

[image]

But when i open it in TileMill, it converts image like this. White areas are transparent in the image

[image]

This is more like, it removes all no data values i.e. 255 in my original image. How can i set custom no data value with TileMill and also set RGB bands null value to null. I don't want RB

Comment: What kind of image is that? Which extension? How do you import it into TileMill?

Comment: It's geotiff file with .tif extension. I am importing it using Add Layer from TileMill.

Comment: Did you add `band=1` as input in the Advanced input area? What happens if you type in CartoCSS the following command `raster-colorizer-default-mode: exact`?

Comment: I have tried tha, but still the same results are generated.

Comment: What happens if you open the same GeoTIFF in QGIS or ArcGIS etc.? Have you tried to play with [VRT](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html) and to set up an XML for your GeoTIFF?

Comment: When i open it in ArcGIS, It does remove the NO DATA values that is 255. But if i tell arcgis or qgis to uncheck no data value to 255, then it works perfect in QGIS.

Comment: Have you seen this thread already [Tilemill and GeoTiff not working together](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147311/tilemill-and-geotiff-not-working-together)? You may try using ['gdalwarp'](https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) for increasing work/cache memory. How large is your GeoTIFF?

Comment: It's not very large Geotiff file. It's around 50MB. There is another thing that i am doing for these maps i.e. I published them in GeoServer and changed RGB values to null and changed noData values to "White". This did the trick for me on GeoServer, but that did not worki in TileStache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct solution to this problem as per my knowledge. But there 
is a workaround that can be used to solve the problem with map.

**Do these steps in ArcMap**

1) Clip your raster by the boundary using image analysis window.

2) Export the raster in "tif" format with **Nodata value = 0**

**Do these steps in TileMill**

3) Open tilemill project. Add the clipping boundary and add this line
 in cartocss of boundary:

```
background-color: #000
```

4) overlay your raster 3 times individual bands. Add band = 1 in advanced setting then for 2nd time add band = 2, and then band = 3 and add this style:

```
#red {
  raster-scaling:gaussian;
  raster-comp-op:plus;
  raster-colorizer-default-mode:linear;
  raster-colorizer-default-color: transparent;
  raster-colorizer-epsilon:0.1;
  raster-colorizer-stops:
    stop(0,#000)
    stop(255,rgb(255,0,0))
}
#green {
  raster-scaling:gaussian;
  raster-comp-op:plus;
  raster-colorizer-default-mode:linear;
  raster-colorizer-default-color: transparent;
  raster-colorizer-epsilon:0.1;
  raster-colorizer-stops:
    stop(0,#000)
    stop(255,rgb(0,255,0))
}
#blue {
  raster-scaling:gaussian;
  raster-comp-op:plus;
  raster-colorizer-default-mode:linear;
  raster-colorizer-default-color: transparent;
  raster-colorizer-epsilon:0.1;
  raster-colorizer-stops:
    stop(0,#000)
    stop(255,rgb(0,0,255))
}
```

It will give you exact results you need.

Comment: thanks! It worked for me. You are super genius.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you, @gis-professional.